# Inserting multiple rows into a table using a single INSERT statement

Tags: sql, netezza, squirrel-sql

I have no idea why I cannot insert values into my table using this syntax. I can insert one row but I cannot insert multiple rows.

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (
             ID BIGINT NULL,
             CAT VARCHAR(255) NULL,
             M_ID BIGINT NULL,
             T_CAT  VARCHAR(255) NULL,
             NUM BIGINT NULL) 

    INSERT INTO T1
    VALUES
    (32,'Math',945,'Red',2),
    (6,'English',232,'Blue',2)
```

Comment: Which DBMS is this? Off the top of my head, you may need to list the columns you're inserting in parentheses after the table name.

Comment: I am using SquirrelSQL with Netezza

Comment: Works fine in [SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f6a08/1) 
[MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6a08/2) and [Postgre](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/f6a08/3) are you getting an error?

Comment: Yes, ^ found "INSERT" (at char 154) expecting a keyword

SQLState:  HY000
ErrorCode: 1100

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax is correct. However, inserting multiple rows is a SQL-92 feature. Seems like your database doesn't support it.

Comment: are you sure this feature is included in the SQL92 spec? I was taking a look at it at 13.8 section, and could find it.

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitly defining the column you want to insert into:

```
INSERT INTO T1 (ID, CAT, M_ID, T_CAT, NUM)
VALUES
(32,'Math',945,'Red',2),
(6,'English',232,'Blue',2)
```

See [this working example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/efd07/2)

Comment: Since the number of values match the number of columns, it should work without listing the columns too, right? (Even though it might be bad practice)

Comment: Do you think that I would explain "I can insert one row but I cannot insert multiple rows."

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that all databases support inserting multiple rows using the VALUES statement.  You can use separate insert statements:

```
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES  (32,'Math',945,'Red',2);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES  (6,'English',232,'Blue',2);
```

Or, you could use a SELECT syntax instead:

```
INSERT INTO T1
    select 32,'Math',945,'Red',2 union all
    select 6,'English',232,'Blue',2
```

(Note:  I used SQL Server syntax for getting constants out.  You might need to add something like "from dual".)

Finally, I fully agree with other posters that putting the list of columns after the table name is such good practice that you should do it automatically.  Well, another good practice is to have an auto-incremented id column, and if you have one of those, you need the list of columns.

However, not having the list should not be causing your problem.

Comment: The problem is that I have 1000 rows, and I want to use the values statement to input all the rows to my table. Is there a way I could import these rows from a text file?

Comment: Absolutely, but that is highly database dependent.  I might suggest something else.  Load the table into Excel and write an Excel formula to create the INSERT statements.  Then copy all those insert statements in bulk and run them.  Just an idea, but quite handy for one-time loads.

Comment: By the way, you can do the same thing by constructing the "select ... union all" form of the insert query.  This would run much faster for 1000 rows.

Answer (score 1):

This particular error is because you didn't terminate your CREATE TABLE statement with a semicolon.  Netezza requires statements to be terminated, it doesn't intelligently parse multi-statement queries.

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (
         ID BIGINT NULL,
         CAT VARCHAR(255) NULL,
         M_ID BIGINT NULL,
         T_CAT  VARCHAR(255) NULL,
         NUM BIGINT NULL); 

INSERT INTO T1
VALUES
(32,'Math',945,'Red',2),
(6,'English',232,'Blue',2);
```

It's also probable that the next error you encounter is going to be Gordon's response, since NZ doesn't really support any of the advanced VALUES clause options.

Answer (score 0):

As most of the above answers have correctly explained that Netezza does not support the VALUES clause as it belongs to SQL-92 class which NZ is unfamiliar with, you could as well use the nzload tool shipped with Netezza clients to load your data at one shot.

The command to load data from a CSV file into a NZ table would be :

```
nzload -host <host> -u <username> -pw <password> -db <db_name> -t <table_name> -delim ',' -df <data_file>
```

Answer (score 0):

Netezza supports bulk uploading in SQL. The non-standard EXTERNAL TABLE replaces the regular table with a CSV flat-file. This can be used inside an INSERT...SELECT... statement.

Notice the **USING** clause has no commas separating terms (I got bit by that). Also, a PIPE delimiter and **ODBC** are set because I use pyODBC. **JAVA** is another **REMOTESOURCE**. The **skiprows 1** term discards the header.

```
INSERT INTO NetezzaTable
SELECT *
FROM EXTERNAL 'C:\\temp\\Your.csv'
USING (
delimiter '|'
REMOTESOURCE 'ODBC'
LOGDIR 'C:\\temp'
skiprows 1
maxerrors 0
fillrecord);
```