# Netezza - insert multiple rows is slow

Tags: sql, netezza

How do I insert multiple rows at the same time in Netezza? I have about 20k records to insert but it takes 1 hr (!) to put them all in using single inserts

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, 2, 2, 'E') , (3, 4, 5, 'Z') --doesn't work
```

This is what I'm using right now

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, 2, 2, 'E'); 
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (3, 4, 5, 'Z');
...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting into Table using SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744662/inserting-into-table-using-sql)

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't work? or it is working but it is slow? They are two different questions.

Comment: If you're inserting records row by row, you should rethink why you are using a database optimized for millions of rows to be loaded per batch.

Answer (score 8):

Netezza does not perform well with singleton updates or inserts.  What we've done is Upserts or what we call Kill and Fills.  Using Cognos Data Manager (ETL) we find all the updates and then delete them from the table before we use NZ Load to append them back.  For inserts, we just append them.  Both using NZ Load.  Works much better than the slow and painful single (one at a time) updates or inserts.

Comment: Don't forget that depending on how much you Update, you need a Grooming process for the tables since if you're Upserting a few million rows/day, your table will be growing quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Not every database supports multiple row inserts. So you will have to use separate inserts or you can also use:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE
select 2, 2, 2, 'E' union all
select 3, 4, 5, 'Z'
```

Answer (score 2):

Netezza Performance Server (NPS) is mainly focuses on Online Analytic Transactions (OLAP). It mainly concerns with Bulk loading. So if your insertion records are huge, go for NZLOAD which will be very fast.
Syntax:
nzload -db  -host  -u  -pw  -t  -df  -delim  -dateDelim   -lf   -bf